# No such file or directory при выполнении элементарного скрипта

Tags: ubuntu, bash

под root выполняю скрипт fs.sh, находящийся  в /var/

скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
echo 1
cd /
```

получаю ошибку:

```
root@bill2:/var# bash fs.sh
1
: No such file or directory
root@bill2:/var#
```

Помогите разобраться, почему скриптом не могу попасть в каталог, а если в консоли набрать `cd /` то прекрасно перехожу.

Содержимое файла:

```
$ od -bc fs.sh
0000000 043 041 057 142 151 156 057 142 141 163 150 040 055 170 015 012
          #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h       -   x  \r  \n
0000020 145 143 150 157 040 061 015 012 143 144 040 057 015 012
          e   c   h   o       1  \r  \n   c   d       /  \r  \n
0000036
```

Comment: Посмотрите на текст скрипта каким-нибудь `hd` (или  `od -bc` )

Comment: root@bill2:/var# od -bc fs.sh
0000000 043 041 057 142 151 156 057 142 141 163 150 040 055 170 015 012
          #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h       -   x  \r  \n
0000020 145 143 150 157 040 061 015 012 143 144 040 057 015 012 043 126
          e   c   h   o       1  \r  \n   c   d       /  \r  \n

Comment: А если его пересоздать через тот же `nano` или `gedit`, `kate`? Вот прям из вопроса скопировать и вставить уже в редакторе?

Comment: `\r` в конце строк уберите (т.е. строки должны заканчиваться `\n`)  (ну, в крайнем случае, если не справитесь, то после `/` в `cd /` вбейте пробел (можно несколько))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

содержимое вашего скрипта:

```
$ od -bc файл
0000000 043 041 057 142 151 156 057 142 141 163 150 040 055 170 015 012
          #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h       -   x  \r  \n
0000020 145 143 150 157 040 061 015 012 143 144 040 057 015 012
          e   c   h   o       1  \r  \n   c   d       /  \r  \n
0000036
```

видно, что строки оканчиваются двумя символами: `\r\n` ([cr+lf](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)).

а должны заканчиваться одним символом `\r` (cr).

преобразовать файл можно, например, с помощью программы *dos2unix* (в популярных дистрибутивах операционной системы *gnu/linux* обычно входит в одноимённый пакет):

```
$ dos2unix /путь/к/файлу
```

---

обратное преобразование:

```
$ unix2dos /путь/к/файлу
```

---

справку смотрите командой `man dos2unix`.

Comment: Спасибо! Переписал в nano и все заработало