# bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'done'

Tags: bash

Не работает баш скрипт, подскажите в чём проблема?
лог ошибки:

```
$ /bin/bash ~/engine-daemon.sh
/home/user/engine-daemon.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
/home/user/engine-daemon.sh: line 7: ` done'
```

Сам скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]
do
cd /home/user/engine
php engine.php
sleep 10;
done
```

Comment: Кажется, символ ";" в конце 6-й строки (перед "done") является лишним

Comment: `;` - не ошибка: в самом скрипте в вопросе ошибки синтаксиса нет

Comment: Чего произойдёт если сказать ему `while [ 1 ]; do cd /home/user/engine; php -r 'print_r(1);'; sleep 1; done` ?

Comment: P.S. Не знаю чего Вы делаете, но заранее посоветую вместо `while true` использовать `supervisord` :)

Comment: приведите в порядок переводы строк: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/547489/178576

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [No such file or directory при выполнении элементарного скрипта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547449/no-such-file-or-directory-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: Прежде чем спрашивать необходимо как минимум указать что данный скрипт стартует Демон.
Кроме того в данном скрипте должен быть указан полный путь, а не так, что вы взяли файл из движка аукциона и как там и было написано, так и запустили.
Необходимо полностью настраивать верно, а не методом тыка.)))