# Bash error: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, unix

Получаю

```
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

при попытке выполнить скрипт. Что не так в скрипте? (проверял в https://www.shellcheck.net/ вроде как все зеленое)

```
#!/bin/sh
PROCESS_COUNT=$(ps aux | grep my-program | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | wc -l)

if [ $PROCESS_COUNT != 0 ] ; then 
    ps aux | grep my-program | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
fi

FINAL_RESULT=$(ps aux | grep my-program | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | wc -l)
if [ $FINAL_RESULT != 0 ] ; then 
    echo "error thrown"
fi
```

Comment: line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file - это следующая за последним fi

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/547489/178576

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547449/no-such-file-or-directory-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0/547489#547489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут представлено решение, проблема была в том, что текстовый редактор приписывал символы \r\n вместо только \r как требует unix.
Решение взято отсюда [ответ со стекоферфлоу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547449/no-such-file-or-directory-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0/547489#547489)

Вот тут описано как такое проделать использовав notepad ++

[как удалить \n используя notepad++](http://www.fortress-design.com/kak-udalit-simvol-konca-stroki/)

Answer (score 1):

Вместо подсчета количества процессов в качестве страховки от вызова `kill` без аргументов, гораздо удобнее использовать цикл `while read`, поскольку при отсутствии элементов в списке процессов он просто не запустится. К примеру так:

```
#!/bin/bash
my_program=sublime_text # к примеру
while read -r pid
do
    kill -9 "${pid}"
done < <(awk '$11 ~ my_program {print $2}' my_program="${my_program}" < <(ps aux))
```

Answer (score 0):

в моем случае спасла замена табуляции на двойной пробел